# Angularjs: best practice for sharing data between sibling directives via parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directives nested under a single controller. When I hover over an element in the first directive I want to highlight related elements in the second directive. Currently, I emit an event and the data in my first directive:

```
// on hover
$scope.$emit('highlight', elms);
```

which the controller listens for and then broadcasts a new event and the data:

```
$scope.$on('highlight', function (event, elms) {
    $scope.$broadcast('highlight-child', elms);
});
```

which my second directive listens for:

```
$scope.$on('highlight-child', function (event, elms) {
    // highlight the elements
});
```

I guess my main question is if there is a better way for the first directive or controller to tell the second directive to do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative would be to have them communicate through a service which you would inject into each.

The service isolates that communication nicely but the advantages are marginal as far as I can see, besides perhaps performance if it is called very frequently.

On top of that I think you could also have them communicate via a shared object on the parent's scope, passing that to each directive's isolate scope.

Answer (score 1):

The service is a good solution but you can try the following as well:

In your first directive you can do the following instead of $emit the event:

```
$scope.$parent.$broadcast('highlight-child', elms);
```

In your section directive just catch the event:

```
$scope.$on('highlight-child', function (event, elms) {
    // highlight the elements
});
```